# Split ArrayList of sentences into words, store the words into new ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I've done some research, and maybe I'm just not asking the right questions.

I have an ArrayList of sentences. I want to split the sentences and store individual words into a new ArrayList to use later. I've included code.

This is my first post. If something is incorrect, I apologize in advance.

FYI, rawLinesTest is my ArrayList of sentences.

```
public List<String> getRawWords() 
{
    String[] tokens = rawLinesTest.toArray(new String[0]);
    for(String s : tokens)
    {
    tokens = s.split("[^\\w]+");
    rawWords = Arrays.asList(tokens); 
    }

return rawWords;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
public ArrayList<String> getRawWords(String s) 
{
   String[]  s2 = s.split(" ");
   ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

   for(int x =0; x< s2.length-1;x++)
   {
        words.add(s2[x]);
   }
   return words;
}
```

To use later just assign a arraylist to the returned list....

```
String sentence = "A Test Sentence";
ArrayList<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();
q = getRawWords(sentence);
```